# Django: Assign html options to model

Tags: django

I have a form with fields. The view consists of html-options. They should be always updated, because maybe someone is saving something on another tab.

The html-options shows all my models (the text is self-assembled through the value of `name` and `adress` in `Wohnungseinheiten`) which doesn't have filled the column "GROUP". 
It also shows the text-option "add a new group", because I want to redirect to a page to create the model.

When I choose a model from the options, then I want to assign the model in the column "GROUP".

How can I assign text to the model (`add new Wohnungseinheiten` means that it has NONE)?

**HTML**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  var my_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#output_box').load('user/mietgruppe/mietgruppe_answer/');
  }, 1000);
});
</script>

<form class="form-signin" action="mietgruppe" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-control" name="wohnungsgruppenname" type="text" placeholder="Mietgruppenname">

    <select class="form-control" name="wohnungseinheiten">
      <option>Neue Wohnung anlegen</option>
          <div id="output_box"></div>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**My model:**

```
class Wohnungsgruppe(model.Models):
    wohnungsgruppenname = models.CharField(
        "wohnungsgruppenname", max_length=100, unique=True)
    wohnungseinheiten = models.ForeignKey(
        Wohnungseinheiten, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

**My form:**

```
class MietgruppeCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    wohnungsgruppenname = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    wohnungseinheiten = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Wohnungsgruppe
        fields = ('wohnungsgruppenname', 'wohnungseinheiten')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        m = super().save(commit)
        if wohnungseinheiten == "Neue Wohnung anlegen":
           setattr(self, 'wohnungseinheiten',None)
        if commit:
            m.save()
        return m
```